# Updating Php 5.6.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: php

my question is how to update Php 5.6.0 on ubuntu if my folder with php5 is at:

```
etc/php5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download php 5.6 from https://www.php.net/downloads.php
2. untar/unzip the package.
3. In package type `./configure`
4. type `make`
5. type `make install`

Notice: after `./configure` they might ask you to install some other packages clearly written on error log. php 5.6 has major patch which supports more than 2Gib file uploads.

Comment: Can you make your commands more noob-friendly please? That means a user should just be able to copy-paste the commands. Thanks!